# I need a bootstrap nav bar to this slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Full Window Image Gallery](http://codepen.io/dh4/pen/Lprdba)
 I need a bootstrap `navbar` on top and a half height of this slider as it is full window slider.... so that i could keep more  below the slider.

Comment: What is your try brother?

Comment: i kept bootstrap nav bar but its colliding

Comment: I can't see any navbar code in your shared link.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried.